# echo results with DIV

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to get results into my html page from a `mysql db` using an external php file. I want to be able to echo the results together with the DIV tags so I can get the results including the DIVs into the html page. How do I add the DIV (below) in to the `mysqli_fetch_array` results and echo the results?

php

```
while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        $price = $line["cost"];
        $item = $line["item"];
        $img = $line["image"];
}
```

DIV

```
<div id="box-1" class="box">
        <gt_descA>$item</gt_descA><gt_descC>$price</gt_descC>
            <img id = $img/>
                <span class="caption simple-caption">
                <div class="minibuttonR"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
                <div class="minibuttonL"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: do some googling for Ajax with PHP

Comment: Can't I add the DIV inside of the while tag to echo back to the html?

Comment: you can refer to this article about jquery ajax,http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. you can make a ajax call to the remote php script which would extract the required data from DB and return back, which can be received at client side and include it under which ever div tag inside the html page

Comment: @NathaliaZeed: you can construct a div tag with all relevant data in it and echo it.it will work, but to make asynchronous call, you may have to use ajax

Comment: @dreamweiver : that's the sort of answer I was expecting. Thanks dreamweiver.

Comment: @dreamweiver : Are you able to show an example of how the echo statement should be written in the php file? (I'm a little lost because there are so many lines in my DIV)

Answer (score 3):

I think you looking for this:-

```
<?php
while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        $price = $line["cost"];
        $item = $line["item"];
        $img = $line["image"];
?>  

<div id="box-1" class="box">
        <gt_descA>$item</gt_descA><gt_descC>$price</gt_descC>
            <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="" />
                <span class="caption simple-caption">
                <div class="minibuttonR"><a href="index.html" onClick=""><?php echo $item; ?></a></div>
                <div class="minibuttonL"><a href="index.html" onClick=""><?php echo  $price; ?></a></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </span>
</div>

<?php   
}
?>
```

Comment: Pleasure to help you :) You can mark it solutions if really help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply echo the div's as well from PHP. Since all PHP output is in HTML, the div's and all other html elements that you echo will be rendered as HTML.

For you question, you can echo something like this

```
echo '<div id="box-1" class="box">
<gt_descA>'.$item.'</gt_descA><gt_descC>'.$price.'</gt_descC>
<img id = '.$img.'/>
<span class="caption simple-caption">
<div class="minibuttonR"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
<div class="minibuttonL"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</span>
</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for inserting PHP generated content into the current page, then use PHP to add your HMTL to your PHP data, like so:

```
while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    $price = $line['cost'];
    $item = $line['item'];
    $img = $line['image'];
    echo '<div id=box-1 class=box>';
    echo "<gt_descA>$item</gt_descA><gt_descC>$price</gt_descC>";
    echo "<img id=$img />";
    echo "<span class='caption simple-caption'>";
    echo '<div class=minibuttonR><a href=index.html onClick=></a></div>';
    echo '<div class=minibuttonL><a href=index.html onClick=></a></div>';
    echo '<div style=clear:both;></div>';
    echo '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
<div id="box-1" class="box">
<?
while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
?>
     <gt_descA><?php echo $line["item"] ?></gt_descA><gt_descC <?php echo $line["cost"]; ?></gt_descC>
                <img id = "<? echo $line["image"] ?>"/>
                    <span class="caption simple-caption">
                    <div class="minibuttonR"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
                    <div class="minibuttonL"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </span>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you're not saving any values.

i think is something like this...

```
<?php
    $lines = array();
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        $lines[] = $line;
    }

    return $lines;
?>
```

In View...

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++): ?>
<div id="box-<?php echo $i+1 ?>" class="box">
    <gt_descA><?php echo $item = $line["item"]; ?></gt_descA><gt_descC><?php echo $line["cost"]; ?></gt_descC>
        <img id ="<?php $line["image"]; ?>" />
            <span class="caption simple-caption">
                <div class="minibuttonR"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
                <div class="minibuttonL"><a href="index.html" onClick=""></a></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </span>
</div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```